# Select where CONVERT() in NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, icriteria

Hello I want to generate a sql query with ICriteria interface like that

`select * from tableName where (dataColumn like '%2010-06-09%')`

I researched in google and I found CONVERT() function to do this:

`SELECT * FROM DATE_SAMPLE 
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10),SAMPLE_DATE,120) = '2003-04-09'`

How can I do this in NHibernate wtih ICriteria?

Comment: I don't know how to write it directly in Criterion but if you can use Query/QueryOver then you can write: Where(x => x.StartDate.Date == myDate.Date) - Assuming that your datatype is a DateTime to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should keep dates (and times and datetimes) in a suitable datatype (e.g. DateTime) rather than treating them as string. Can you not just pass a DateTime into ICriteria?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create your own criteria using.  Check out the following:

http://xlib.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/integrating-freetext-search-in-nhibernate-detached-criteria/